# Access a new frames methods

Tags: java, swing, class

This method shows a new window in my application:

```
public void ShowNewCustomerView() {
    if (NewCustomer == null) NewCustomer = new NewCustomerView(this);
    NewCustomer.setVisible(true);
}
```

The class NewCustomerView has this method:

```
public void ClearFields() {
    txtAddress.setText("");
    txtCity.setText("");
    txtCompanyName.setText("");
    txtCustomerNumber.setText("");
    txtOrganisationNumber.setText("");
    txtPhoneNumber1.setText("");
    txtPhoneNumber2.setText("");
    txtPostalCode.setText("");
    txtReferenceName.setText("");
}
```

How can I run that method before the line:

```
NewCustomer.setVisible(true);
```

Adding this:

```
NewCustomer.ClearFields();
```

...does not work... why is that?

This is what error I get:
Cannot find symbol (method ClearFields())
Class: javax.Swing.JFrame

But I created a new instance of NewCustomerView which extends JFrame?? Right?

Comment: How is it not working? Is there text content in those fields?

Comment: Updated post, see why above...

Comment: Sorry for racing with edits, thought to make one small edit at the same time as you - SO apparently doesn't check concurrent edits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I think you declare `NewCustomer` like this:

```
JFrame NewCustomer;
```

If so try declaring:

```
NewCustomerView NewCustomer;
```

or

```
public void ShowNewCustomerView() {
    if (NewCustomer == null) NewCustomer = new NewCustomerView(this);
    ((NewCustomerView)NewCustomer).ClearFields();
    NewCustomer.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your defining your new Frame as:

```
JFrame frame = new NewCustomerView();
```

Instead you should be doing:

```
NewCustomerView frame = NewCustomerView();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following error message is a hint as to what is going on:

```
Cannot find symbol (method ClearFields()) Class: javax.Swing.JFrame
```

What the message is saying is that there is a call to the `ClearFields` method on a `JFrame` object. This makes sense, as there is no `ClearFields` method on the `JFrame` object.

What this seems to indicate is that the `NewCustomerView` object is being declared as a `JFrame` rather than a `NewCustomerView`.

I'm going to guess the line which declares the `NewCustomer` object is written like this:

```
JFrame NewCustomer = new NewCustomerView();
```

What that is doing is to handle the new `NewCustomerView` object as a `JFrame` -- therefore, when trying to call the `ClearFields` method, one is trying to call the `JFrame.ClearFields` method, which doesn't exist.

Try the following instead, so the object that is being declared is handled as a `NewCustomerView` object:

```
NewCustomerView NewCustomer = new NewCustomerView();
```

Also as a note, in Java, variable names are written with a lower-case letter, followed by uppercase letter for each word boundary, for example, in the above example, `NewCustomer` would be written `newCustomer`.